# CasperJS : how to call __doPostBack

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler, phantomjs, casperjs, dopostback

I am trying to scrap a page : 
http://fd1-www.leclercdrive.fr/057701/courses/pgeWMEL009_Courses.aspx#RS284323

But as you can see this link redirect to 
fd1-www.leclercdrive.fr/057701/courses/pgeWMEL009_Courses.aspx 
**when you first access it. after you click on "fruits et légumes" you can access the page using the url directly**

So I need to simulate a click on the button "Fruits et légumes" to access the page I want. In the code, it does a dopostback

Here is my code that I use with `casperj`s :

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
verbose: true,
logLevel: "debug"
});


casper.start('http://fd1-www.leclercdrive.fr/057701/courses/pgeWMEL009_Courses.aspx#RS284323');

// here i simulate the click on "Fruits et légumes"
casper.evaluate(function() {
   __doPostBack('objLienReceptdionEvenement','2@@284323');
});


casper.then(function() {
console.log(' new location is ' + this.getCurrentUrl());
});

casper.run();
```

I still be redirected to the wrong page

Answer (score 1):

The call to __doPostBack is not correct (extra 'd' in `'objLienReceptdionEvenement'`)

Should be

```
// here i simulate the click on "Fruits et légumes"
casper.evaluate(function() {
   __doPostBack('objLienReceptionEvenement','2@@284323');
})
```

Comment: this is not working for me. OP, were you able to use this example? I have the same issue and cannot understand what's going on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25107976/cannot-navigate-with-casperjs-evaluate-and-dopostback-function