# CasperJS Invoke Javascript function on browser console

Tags: javascript, methods, dom-events, phantomjs, casperjs

I am trying to invoke a Javascript method using CasperJS.
The web page simply consist of a link that allows me to change back to my default country.

```
<a id="defaultCountry" href="javascript:__doPostBack('cty$UK$default','')">Default Country</a>
```

I want CasperJS to invoke the Javascript method that is called after clicking the link.
I assumed that mimicking a mouse click on the link would invoke the Javascript method but it doesn't.
I've tried the following methods with no success:

```
 casper.then(function() {
        casper.click(x('//*[@id="defaultCountry"]'));
        casper.evaluate(function() {
              __doPostBack('cty$UK$default',''); //this is the javascript function. im not sure if thats how you would call it though
        });
```

or

```
this.clickLabel('Default Country', 'a');
```

I know that if I invoke the Javascript function on the browser console, it will work. I simply type:

```
__doPostBack('cty$UK$default','');
```

in the console and it magically works.
Any help appreciated!

---

Edit:

@Rippo This is a snippet of what I ran. It seems like CasperJS bypasses my eval statement. The last few lines are from the console directly. I know my page loads with the selector because of the screenshot. I've even used the `casper.waitforselector` method to confirm.

```
casper.thenOpen('http://example.com');

casper.wait(5000, function() {
    console.log('page opened');
    casper.capture('page.png');
    console.log('capture page complete');
});

casper.thenEvaluate(function() {
    console.log('invoking javascript');
    __doPostBack('cty$UK$default','');
    console.log('javascript invoked');
});
```

This is from the console:

```
[info] [phantom] wait() finished waiting for 5000ms.
page opened
[debug] [phantom] Capturing page to C:/Users/page.png
[info] [phantom] Capture saved to C:/Users/page.png
capture page complete
[info] [phantom] Step _step 8/8 http://example.com (HTTP 200)
[info] [phantom] Step _step 8/8: done in 16240ms.
[info] [phantom] Done 8 steps in 16259ms
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=about:blank, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] url changed to "about:blank"
```

This is the last line from the console before it exits.

---

Edit 7/17/2016 12:40AM

@Artjom B.
Here's a snippet of the code I ran with your suggestions:

```
...snipped some prior    
function() {
    console.log('Page loaded');
    casper.capture('page.png');
    console.log('Starting 1st postback call');
    this.evaluate(function() {
        console.log('postback call');
         __doPostBack('cty$UK$default','');
        });
    console.log('passed postback');
    casper.capture('post-postback.png');

//At this point, it skips this function and goes straight to console.log then comes back to this function. Not sure why...
casper.then(function() {
    console.log('trying to change again');
    this.click(x('//*[@id="defaultCountry"]'));
    this.evaluate(function() {
        __doPostBack('cty$UK$default','');
        console.log('javascript invoked');
    });
});

//skipped to this console.log
console.log('waiting country to change');
this.waitForSelector('.countryuk', 
    function() {
        console.log('country change completed. Capturing image');
        this.capture('uk.png');
    },

    function() {
        console.log('timed out waiting for country to change.');
        this.capture('uk-timeout.png');
    },5000);
```

};

Here is the console output:

```
Page loaded
[debug] [phantom] Capturing page to C:/Users/page.png
[info] [phantom] Capture saved to C:/Users/page.png
Starting 1st postback call
Console: postback call
Error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: __doPostBack
passed postback
[debug] [phantom] Capturing page to C:/Users/post-postback.png
[info] [phantom] Capture saved to C:/Users/post-postback.png
waiting country to change
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 10/11 http://example.com/page.aspx?r=2 (HTTP 200)
trying to change again
[debug] [phantom] Mouse event 'mousedown' on selector: xpath selector: //*[@id="defaultCountry"]
[debug] [phantom] Mouse event 'mouseup' on selector: xpath selector: //*[@id="defaultCountry"]
[debug] [phantom] Mouse event 'click' on selector: xpath selector: //*[@id="defaultCountry"]
Error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: __doPostBack
Error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: __doPostBack
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 10/11: done in 22567ms.
[info] [phantom] Step _step 11/11 http://example.com/page.aspx?r=2 (HTTP 200)
[info] [phantom] Step _step 11/11: done in 22573ms.
[warning] [phantom] Casper.waitFor() timeout
timed out waiting for country to change.
[debug] [phantom] Capturing page to C:/Users/uk-timeout.png
[info] [phantom] Capture saved to C:/Users/uk-timeout.png
[info] [phantom] Done 11 steps in 27825ms
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=about:blank, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] url changed to "about:blank"
```

Clearly it cant find the postback function. I'm not sure why though. It's not a hidden element. It's exactly as I posted above (a link). It's nested within a bunch of div tags but that's about it.

Comment: I've seen similar issues with the postback calls  My issue is that Casperjs doesnt process my eval function and I'm not sure why. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25107976/cannot-navigate-with-casperjs-evaluate-and-dopostback-function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17830597/casperjs-how-to-call-dopostback

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-2_caspererrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: You haven't answered my first question. Anyway, you have to find out why the request that loads the `__doPostBack` function isn't being loaded. Is it an HTTPS request?

Answer (score 1):

what about just (remove `casper.then` and `casper.click`)

```
 casper.thenEvaluate(function() {
       __doPostBack('cty$UK$default',''); 
 });
```

Comment: as a side note `console.log('invoking javascript');` inside evaluate with echo to the web browsers console not the command console you run it from. I wonder if the JS has finished loading? I suspect you have an JS error somewhere on page. See @artjom comment

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `href` of the link and use the `eval` function.

```
var str = document.getElementById("defaultCountry").href;
eval(str.substring(str.indexOf(":") + 1));
```

Comment: Once I declar var str, CasperJS breaks out. I put console.log prior and after your code. It would interpret the console.log prior but not after.

Comment: @kubermeso What do you mean "breaks out"? Where are you putting the declaration and eval call?

Comment: Please see my edit above. I put your statements within the casper.thenEvaluate function. I've also ttried it with casper.wait. Neither work and casperjs just bypasses the code

Comment: `"defaultValue"` is nowhere to be found in the question and your code contains a syntax error. There is a `)` missing

Comment: @ArtjomB. afuous: I put your statement in after my console.log('Starting 1st postback call'). It breaks the script. Here's the last few lines from my console: Starting 1st postback call [info] [phantom] Done 9 steps in 22260ms
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=about:blank, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] url changed to "about:blank"

Comment: PhantomJS is perfectly capable of executing such href code. There is no need to `eval` it.